# How much work can a single grain of rice do?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, gravity, work

I found a website saying a grain of rice contains 1/10  kcal.

I'm not a physicist and haven't done maths for a long time. But here's what I came up with:

E = m * g * h

- One small calorie equals 4.184 joules.
- One grain of rice = 1/10 kcal = 100 cal
- 100 cal = 418.4 Joules

**Assume a weight of 10kg**

418.4 J = 10kg * 9.81 N * h

418.4 = 98.1 * h

418.4 / 98.1 = h

h = 4.26m

**Therefore it can raise:**

- 1kg 42.6m into the air
- 10kg 4.26m into the air
- 100kg .426m into the air

**Or:**

- 42.6kg 1m into the air
- 4.26kg 10m into the air
- .426kg 100m into the air

This seems like a lot! Are my calculations correct?

Comment: Looks right to me. And if you converted the entire mass of a grain of rice (about 25 mg) to energy ($mc^2$) then you'd get more than a billion times as much energy.

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE! Please take not of [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and that [check-my-work questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are off-topic. Also, you can use [MathJaX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020) here to typeset formulae correctly.

Comment: Although this is a fun question, it really isn't on-topic since there is nothing to answer.

Comment: @lemon Saaay whaaaaaat?! How can this be so much more? What is the difference between "the entire mass" that you talk about and the 100 calories that I've assumed are in the rice? Would you be including things like water and fiber and so on that that body can't use as energy but do contain energy?

Comment: @user43107 $E=mc^2$ tells us that mass is energy, and that a small mass corresponds to a huge amount of energy (which is why nuclear weapons are so powerful). The 100 calories you're talking about is merely the *chemical* energy that our body is able to extract from the rice by breaking down the constituent carbohydrates and so on.

Comment: @ACuriousMind / Chris - sorry about not reading the guidelines, glad it's fun at least!

Comment: @lemon Incredible! So, I found a website saying the space shuttle weighs 165,000 lbs. Which is 74842.7kg. 418,400,000,000 = 74,842.7 * 9.81 * h, therefore 418,400,000,000 = 734,206.887 * h, therefore 418,400,000,000 / 734,206.887 = 569,866.62m. THEREFORE if we could harness the entire energy in a grain of rice it could send the space shuttle 569km into the air. I found a website saying that the exosphere extends to 10,000km, therefore, we would theoretically need 17.59 grains of rice to send a shuttle to space. Only one question remains: Why aren't we growing more of this stuff?!?!

Comment: I have to agree that this question is off topic but fun. I hope you got the answer you were looking for (carbs contain lots of energy! $E=mc^2$ tells us that the energy stored in matter is indeed vast! A tablespoon of antimatter could send the space shuttle into orbit!) and that you will come back with other interesting questions.

Comment: @user43107 You could send the shuttle even further than that (since $g$ decreases as you move away from the earth). But yes, energy content is phenomenal. Unfortunately, releasing energy from matter is easier said than done. Floris hinted at one potential way of achieving it though ([antimatter rockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter_rocket)).